# How I can read a string of boolean operation and give it a priority?

Tags: c++, string

I have to read a file line like this

```
assign x = (c OR (a AND B)) OR (NOT D)
```

Where `assign` is a keyword that active a method of a class called `Logic_gate`, that compute and store the result of the boolean operation.

I read this line from the file by `getline`, and I read this string with a `sstream` object `istringstream`, but I don't know how to give a priority to the operation. I.e I want to do the first the operation between the bracket,then the other one.

In this example I want:

```
-A AND B
-(c OR (a AND B))
-(NOT D)
-(c OR (a AND B)) OR (NOT D)
-Store result in x
```

Comment: Please post your attemps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are looking for a way to convert an infix expression into postfix notation? This lets you build a stack of operations that is trivially easy to evaluate. There's a really ancient expression parser that probably won't compile anymore, but that does the infix to postfix conversion (see the Parse function):  http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Expression_Compiler_Evaluator.shtml

If you know the operator precedence of or/not/and/(), then it should be pretty simple. (You may notice the order of if/else statements in Parse function matches the operator precedence of C++).

.... Obviously I'm not suggesting you compile this down to x86 machine code!! It was just some code I knew had some relevance :)

An extremely simple example:

```
// infix
x = A AND B

// postfix
x = A B AND

// to evaluate
A is a variable, push onto stack
B is a variable, push onto stack
AND is a binary op, so compute:
   stack[last - 1] = stack[last - 1] AND stack[last]
pop a value from the stack

// stack now contains 1 value, the result
```

The original expression:

```
// infix
x = (c OR (a AND B)) OR (NOT D)

// postfix
x = A B AND C OR D NOT OR

// evaluated like so:
A is a var, push on stack
B is a var, push on stack
AND - perform op, pop value from stack, store result in stack.top()
C is a var, push on stack
OR - perform op, pop value from stack, store result in stack.top()
D is a var, push on stack
NOT is unary. store !stack.top() in stack.top(). DO NOT POP!
OR - perform op, pop value from stack, store result in stack.top()

// the stack should contain the result.
```